# No JSON object could be decoded in txt

Tags: json, python-2.7

This is my data in txt:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55"), "meta_version" : "v1.0", "download_data" : { "raw_data" : {  }, "parsed_data" : { "product_type" : "PET", "producer" : "xxx", "price" : "885/kg", "datePublished" : "2018-01-18", "fromLocation" : "", "itemCondition" : "aaa", "priceType" : "1000.0" } }, "download_config" : { "url" : "http://www.1pi.com/price/plist-798-1.html", "method" : "GET" }, "meta_updated" : "2018-01-18T21:39:32" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc56"), "meta_version" : "v1.0", "download_data" : { "raw_data" : {  }, "parsed_data" : { "product_type" : "PET", "producer" : "aaas", "price" : "8750/kg", "datePublished" : "2018-01-18", "fromLocation" : "", "itemCondition" : "AAA", "priceType" : "666.0" } }, "download_config" : { "url" : "http://www.1pi.com/price/plist-798-1.html", "method" : "GET" }, "meta_updated" : "2018-01-18T21:39:32" }
```

This is part of the data in txt, and I'm trying to parse it in JSON. These data are not stored in a row in txt and are unordered. But I have a coding problem in Python 2.

```
def convert(filename):
    dataDict = {}
    print "Opening TXT file: ",filename
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('../txt'):
        for filename in filenames:
            file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            new_file = '../txt/' + os.path.basename(file)
            print(new_file)
            convert(file)
```

> File "E:\python2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
>   ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Use [ in the beginning of the file and ] at the end

Comment: Unless you're reading line by line - you should wrap your data like an array. `[ { }, { } ]`